# python requests posting gifs as octet-stream instead of correct mime type

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to replicate the following curl call in python3 requests.  However, when it sends the file, for some reason its mimeType is being sent as application/octet-stream with size 0.  I've tried every variation of the requests call as I can think of, and I've even tried hard-coding the mimeType and size, but it doesn't change the request my web server is seeing.

Here's the curl call I want to replicate:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://myurl/api/v1/content/createFile \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'postman-token: c35cc623-2cd8-1143-ba64-5870156f7498' \
  -F apiKey=ABCD \
  -F file=@bear.gif
```

Here is the python code I'm trying:

```
import requests
files = {
    'apiKey': (None, 'ABCD'),
    'file': ('bear.gif', open('bear.gif', 'rb')),
}
url = 'http://myurl/api/v1/content/createFile'
response = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Here's what my web server sees from the curl call:

```
"apiKey" => "ABCD"
"file" => UploadedFile {#323 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "bear.gif"
  -mimeType: "image/gif"
  -size: 1283057
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "phpizaC5J"
  basename: "phpizaC5J"
  pathname: "/tmp/phpizaC5J"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/phpizaC5J"
  aTime: 2018-06-01 16:20:30
  mTime: 2018-06-01 16:20:32
  cTime: 2018-06-01 16:20:32
  inode: 1441804
  size: 1283057
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 48
  group: 48
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

And here's what my web server sees when I post from python-requests:

```
"apiKey" => "ABCD"
"file" => UploadedFile {#323 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "bear.gif"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -size: 0
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/var/www/html/myurl"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I found out that it's actually due to the PHP web server's upload_max_filesize being set too low.

My assumption is that the file was being truncated, so it was no longer a valid GIF.  However, I'm not going to research the real reason since it's no longer an issue.